# How to create a boolean method to return value from handler

Tags: java, android, multithreading, methods

I have created a class to check access of internet on device, my class code is

```
public class CheckInternet  {


private static Handler h = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            if (msg.what != 1) { // code if not connected
                status = false;
                System.out.println("Status False");
            } else { // code if connected
                status = true;
                System.out.println("Status True");
            }
        }
    };

private static  void isNetworkAvailable(final Handler handler, final int timeout) {
        new Thread() {
            private boolean responded = false;  
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Thread() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        HttpGet requestForTest = new HttpGet("http://m.google.com");
                        try {
                            new DefaultHttpClient().execute(requestForTest); // can last...
                            responded = true;
                        } catch (Exception e) {}
                    }

                }.start();

                try {
                    int waited = 0;
                    while(!responded && (waited < timeout)) {
                        sleep(100);
                        if(!responded ) { 
                            waited += 100;
                        }
                    }
                } 
                catch(InterruptedException e) {} // do nothing 
                finally { 
                    if (!responded) { handler.sendEmptyMessage(0); 


                    } 
                    else { handler.sendEmptyMessage(1); 
                    }
                }

            }

        }.start();



    }
}
```

I want to create a public static boolean method which returns me the status, I have come up with some code

```
private static Boolean status = true ;    
public static Boolean isConnected() {
            Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    isNetworkAvailable(h,2000);
                }
            };
            runnable.run();
            return status;
        }
```

But the issue is that it always returns me the old status value, as while the time the thread is running, the method send me the old status value.
I want to get the updated status value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You better use

isReachable(timeout)

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#isReachable%28java.net.NetworkInterface,%20int,%20int%29

Regards

Comment: will it work on android device?  public static Boolean test()
 {
  try {
   InetAddress inetAddress  = InetAddress.getByName("www.google.com");
   if(inetAddress.isReachable(1000))
   {
    System.out.println(" is connected");
    return true;
    
   }
   else
   {
    System.out.println(" is not connected");
    return false;
   }
  } catch (Exception e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
   System.err.println(e.getMessage());
   return false;
  }
 } this code is showing not connected though my device is connected.

Comment: In this case, your application can not conntect to www.googe.com.